# How to pass record details dynamically to apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula, controller, custom-field

Objective: To display the URL of VF page as a link on the record detail page and when clicked on that, the VF page should open in a separate tab by taking the record values, such as name dynamically.

What I have achieved till now:

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Project__c" extensions="myExtension">
    <apex:form >
        <html>
           Name of the record: {!currentRecord.Name}
        </html>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class myExtension {

        public project__c currentRecord{get; set;}
        
        public myExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            currentRecord = [SELECT Id, Name FROM project__c  WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        }
    
    }
```

And I have created a formula field that displays the URL of this VF page on the record detail page. It is as follows:

```
HYPERLINK("/apex/Project?recid="&CASESAFEID(Id) , "View Chart", "_blank")
```

But, when I click on the URL, I am getting the following error:

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject An unexpected error has
> occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this scenario?
Thank you advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong parameter name (`recId` where it should be `id`), but you actually shouldn't use page parameters at all here. The `StandardController` class has a `getId()` method, which is *always* how I recommend you get the `Id` if you are still using `Visualforce`.

```
SEELECT ... FROM Project__c WHERE Id = :controller.getId()
```

Note also that a Standard Controller should get the record and its fields for you, no need for a custom extension just to query the record itself. Instead of `{!currentRecord.Name}`, just use `{!Name}`, and you can get rid of your extension altogether.

Comment: Even if i remove extension and pass `{!Project__c.Name}` as value, I am seeing blank output. The output is as follows:

`Name of the record:`

Instead of name, i am seeing blank there. please suggest

Comment: Change `recid` to `id` in your url. You should use the correct parameter names.

Answer (score 1):

When using extensions, you must use the literal parameter `id`:

```
HYPERLINK("/apex/Project?id="&Id , "View Chart", "_blank")
```

Also, instead of a URL like this, you can use $Page instead. This would be future compatible with any changes that Salesforce may make to their URL scheme.

```
URLFOR($Page.Project, Id, null, true)
```

In addition, you do *not* need a query, just get the record from the controller:

```
    public myExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        currentRecord = (Project__c)controller.getRecord();
    }
```